# cuda 7.5 на Visual Studio 13 и Visual Studio 15

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

Поставил себе VS 15 вместо предыдущей VS 12, на которой шаблон cuda отлично добавлялся автоматически. Вот, однако же, проблема. Ни в VS 15, ни в VS 13 этот шаблон не появился. Как его добавить, я что-то не разумею. Подскажите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось поправить. На офиальном сайте [указано](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/#axzz46ldwoV6Q), что CUDA взаимодействует со следующими версиями MSVS:

- Visual C++ 12.0,
- Visual C++ 11.0,
- Visual C++ 10.0 (в следующей версии, скорее всего, не будет поддерживаться),

и MSVC:

- Visual Studio 2013,
- Visual Studio Community 2013 (с ограничениями),
- Visual Studio 2012,
- Visual Studio 2010.

Для того, чтобы конфиги самостоятельно прописались, необходимо сначала установить VS, после этого уже toolkit nVidia CUDA (конфиги будут сгенерена автоматически и nVidia-шаблон появится в проектах).

С VS 15 возникают проблемы, поэтому без очень серьёзной надобности, я не советую лезть настраивать это конфигурацию. Всё про CUDA nVidia 7.5 и VS 15 отвечено [тут](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/883704/when-will-visual-studio-2015-be-supported-/).